# Network transfer pauses

Tags: c#, sockets

I have made a server and a client in C# which transfers files. But when transferring it pauses for some seconds and then continues. I have uploaded a video on YouTube to demonstrate: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGRKRW6ihLo

As you can see it sometime pauses and then continues.

Receiver:

```
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(_localPath, file.FileName))) {
            var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
            while (file.Transferred < file.Size && _active) {
                int read = ns.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                writer.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                file.Transferred += read;
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Sender:

```
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FilePath)) {
                var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
                while (file.Transferred < file.Size && _active) {
                    int read = reader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                    ns.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    file.Transferred += read;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
```

Comment: +1 for the video :-)

Comment: a bit more information would be nice is it a tcp connection or udp? does it just send the file raw over the connection or is there some protocol there? i didn't see a pause in the video what offset? could it be the GC that kicks in when it pauses? does the Interface hang or only the thread that is writing data? when you access the % of the transfer is this done threadsafe?

Comment: TcpClient and TcpListener. I have a protocol. It pauses at 6,2% and 24,03% for example. The interface does not hang. It supports simultaneous file transfers, so i can have two files transferring at the same time and the transfers does not pause at the same time. Yes, that is thread safe i believe, because this happened before i added that functionality.

Comment: if you try moving the code you posted here to a simpler application (console?) does it pause there to? my guess its some thing else and not the code you posted here it seems right...

Comment: Does the video play with pauses on your local machine in a normal video player? I suspect your video encoder introduced the pauses. You code looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
// Sends data immediately upon calling NetworkStream.Write.
tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
```

Send

```
var buffer = new byte[ tcpClient.SendBufferSize ];
```

Read

```
var buffer = new byte[ tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize ];
```

The TcpClient.SendBufferSize and TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize can vary depending on platform. I have in some cases made the buffer half the size or twice the size - of the TcpClient Buffer size.

Comment: I think this made an improvement, but I'm not sure. The pauses are so random so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Nice video....   What is your _bufferSize set to?  Drop down the size and see if it changes the behavior.  My transfers were less lumpy when I cut the size in half.  Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the sendfile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0a40c2.aspx

It uses the kernel to avoid the copying of data around in memory.